# Upgrading to Silverlight 5 sdk?

Tags: silverlight, sdk, silverlight-5.0

How using Silverlight 5 SDK for silverlight 5 applications would help ?
Because we have been using silverlight 4 sdk for all applications till now .
Now people are upgrading to  SL5 . I want to know is moving to silverlight 5 sdk worthwhile ,
because movement is very tedious job .

Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Best you make up your own mind on whether you need any of these features:

[What's new in Silverlight 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg986857%28v=vs.96%29.aspx)

If you do not need any of those features, then do not upgrade.

I would suggest that you start any new development in Silverlight 5, if only for the new binding-debugging feature.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your answer . My case is I have third party assemblies . We will be supporting silverlight 5 browser plugin , because of automatic upgrades. Now when I provide silverlight 5 sdk support , would that mean I also provide support for all the new features introduced . Would that mean i have to make changes in my third party assemblies too ? I am very confused . Please help

Comment: @rahul: The Silverlight 5 plugin is completely backward compatible with earlier version so you do not need to upgrade apps for that reason. It is not clear what service/support you are providing to others so not sure what you mean. Third party assemblies for SL3 & 4 will still work with SL5.